# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate) sending mail

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, jakarta-mail, sslexception

Good morning,

I'm trying to send a mail in a java application running on Ubuntu with jakarta.mail-api version 2.1.2 and openjdk version 11.0.20.1

but I obtain following exception:

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)

Here's my code:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.office365.com"); //SMTP Host
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587"); //TLS Port
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); //enable authentication
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); //enable STARTTLS
props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.protocols", "TLSv1.2");
props.put("mail.debug", "true");

Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {
   protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
      return new PasswordAuthentication("abc@xxxx.com", "yyyy");
   }
};

Session session = Session.getInstance(props, auth);

try {
   MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
   msg.addHeader("Content-type", "text/HTML; charset=UTF-8");
   msg.addHeader("format", "flowed");
   msg.addHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "8bit");

   msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("abc@xxxx.com"));
   msg.setReplyTo(InternetAddress.parse("abc@xxxx.com", false));
   msg.setSubject("Mail Subject");
   msg.setText("body", "UTF-8");
   msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,   InternetAddress.parse("me@xxxx.com", false));
     
   Transport.send(msg);  
    
   log.info("Email Sent Successfully!!");
} catch (Exception e) {
   log.error("Error",e);
}
```

Same code works well on my Windows 11 machine with java version 11.0.19 installed. Any suggestion?

UPDATE:
As suggested by dave_thompson_085 I've changed

```
props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.protocols", "TLSv1.2");
```

in

```
props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.protocols", "TLSv1.3");
```

but exception remains the same.

Checking java.security I've found:

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, RC4, DES, 
MD5withRSA, \
DH keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224, 3DES_EDE_CBC, anon, NULL, \
include jdk.disabled.namedCurves
```

after commenting these three lines Exception become:

```
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: null
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:306) ~[mail-1.4.jar:1.4]
```

after removing only TLSv1, TLSv1.1, I catch always:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
```

Comment: Check jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms in JRE/conf/security/java.security to see if it has (somehow) been set to an undesired or at least unexpected value. Why do you _not_ want TLSv1.3 which is supported by that host (and all Java 11 up)?

Comment: Hi @dave_thompson_085, I've changed to TLSv1.3 and tried to comment jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms lines in java.security but nothing happened.

Answer (score 1):

Your exception has `mail-1.4.jar` as the artifact that is being used.  [JavaMail 1.4](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javamail-api.html) was released on April 25, 2006.

Update your dependencies so mail-1.4.jar is not being directly used or transitively used.

Upgrade to at JavaMail 1.6.4 or newer.